# How to disable buttons/links on a page for certain condition php/html

Tags: php, html, forms

The page is a form, in the header file there are about 6 buttons which determine the page you are one, i want to disable all but the first button if we are on the first page(first button)

Thank you

This is in a foreach loop to fill in all buttons with a different pagename:

```
              echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" id="completeButton" class="menu' . ($page == $p ? '_selected':'') . '" value="' . $p . '">';
```

Comment: Could you post the code you already have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have a page ID somewhere

Do you loop through your buttons to create them ?

If you don't loop through them, you just have to add something like

```
<input type="button" <?php if ($pageId !== 1) echo 'disabled="disabled"' ?> />
```

Then for the second button, you test it with $pageId !== 2 and so on...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<html>
<button type="button">bttn1</button>
<button type="button" disabled="disabled">bttn2</button>
<button type="button" disabled="disabled">bttn3</button>
<button type="button" disabled="disabled">bttn4</button>
<button type="button" disabled="disabled">bttn5</button>
<button type="button" disabled="disabled">bttn6</button>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways but 6 buttons seems confusing and unnecessary for me.

Why don't you create one button labeled 'Next step'?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using session to keep track of where the user is. You could easily check this by checking a session variable:

```
<?php

/**
 * Checks to see if a session key exists and returns the
 * corresponding value otherwise returns false
 *
 * @param <String> $key
 * @return <String/Boolean>
 */

function session($key) {
    if(isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
        return $_SESSION[$key];
    }
    return false;
}

if(!session('curr_page')) {
    // redirect to first page and set the curr page to one
    $_SESSION['curr_page'] = 1;
    header('Location: path/to/your/page.php');
}

$curr_page = session('curr_page');

// now you can use a series of if statements to disable
// the other buttons

?>

<?php if($curr_page > 0): ?>
// display first button etc
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($curr_page > 1): ?>
// display second button etc
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($curr_page > 1): ?>
// display second button etc
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope this helps.